# How to create a desktop entry for .jar files?

Tags: java, executable, zorin

I created a desktop entry and moved it to `~/.local/share/applications`, but it doesn't execute when I click on it from the start menu. This is my `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Categories=Game
Name=Minecraft
Icon=/home/user/Games/Minecraft/Minecraft-icon.png
Exec=/home/user/Games/Minecraft/Minecraft.jar
```

How do I have to modify it to run the `.jar` file from the start menu?

Comment: try Exec=java -jar /home/user/Games/Minecraft/Minecraft.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify that you want to run .jar file. Normally jar are not treated as executable so for `Exec` part you have to add `java -jar` like this:

```
Exec=java -jar /home/user/Games/Minecraft/Minecraft.jar
```